# Trouble running Windows

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I was given an old PC that was upgraded a little (not that much) about half an year ago. Said PC suddenly had some fuzzy image, rebooted and went to a state where it couldn't load it's Windows (8) and stayed on a black screen.

I can't really give you the specs because I haven't taken it apart yet, all I know is the motherboard is ASrock, it uses a 120 GB SSD as a main storage unit, and has it's old 500 GB HDD as additional memory.

When I tried to boot the PC, it tried to load the Windows 8, but then went straight to the black screen. Naturally I decided that Windows simply broke, so I decided to reinstall it, going back to the good old Windows 7. And here is where things went sideways.

- The SSD was practically empty, only had the OS on it, and was shown as one partition of 120 GB.
- I decided to split the space in 2 partitions  - 65 GB and 55 GB (after talking with the owner, that is what he wanted), so naturally the SSD got completely formatted.
- I started the clean installation. It all went smoothly until it reached the part "Installing updates". After the green check showed there, the PC went for a reboot.
- After the reboot, it shows a black screen for a few seconds with text, that says something about registry update, then it resumes the final part of the installation - "Completing installation".
- After a few minutes wait there I get the real problem, a black screen with blinking underscore in the upper left corner.

About the installation method - I tried with both USB and DVD (both of which I've used multiple times, and never had this issue). I made a new USB with a different image. I even tried to install it on the HDD instead of the SSD, but the result was always the same.

At first I thought there might be something wrong with my disk or USB drive, then I thought that something might have happened with the SSD .. either when I partitioned it or before I was given the said PC (even though it's a fairly newly bought device). But when the same thing happened with the HDD I figured the problem must be elsewhere.

My next step is to put the SSD on a different device and try installing windows there, but even if I succeed the problem with this PC still stays, and might brake the new Windows as well. So I would really appreciate any and all suggestion where the problem might lie.

Can it be the CMOS (I can remove the battery in order to reset it), or maybe the RAM could be faulty?? Bad capacitors? I am open to suggestions, but I am almost certain it is a hardware problem, since I get the exact same black screen, at the same moment of the installation, using different installation methods and even the second HDD.